# Normalisation in NoSQL in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, database-normalization

The first table is for products, how would I normalize this data.

- asin - ID of the product, e.g. 1574571931
- categories - list of categories the product belongs to
- description – description of product
- title - name of the product
- brand – brand name of the product

IMAT3104 Database Management and Programming Assignment 2017-18 
De Montfort University 2018 Page 6 of 11

- price - price in US dollars (at time of crawl)
- salesRank - sales rank information. The better the sales, the lower the rank.
- imUrl - url of the product image
- related -

The second table is for reviews and how would I normalize this table as well.

- reviewerID - ID of the reviewer, e.g. A2Y113PST5WPPF
- asin - ID of the product, e.g. 1574571931
- reviewerName - name of the reviewer
- helpful - helpfulness rating of the review, e.g. 2 out of 3 found review helpful
- reviewText - text of the review
- overall - rating of the product
- summary - summary of the review
- unixReviewTime - time of the review (unix time in seconds)
- reviewTime - time of the review (raw)

What is the process of normalization and how can I organize the above 2 tables?

Comment: Hi. This is just asking us to rewrite your textbook & do your (home)work. See my comments on recent [tag:database-normalization] questions including, act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Also what does this have to do with NoSQL or MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Normalization--a strictly logical process--is the same whether the target platform is a SQL dbms, a large scale C++ program, or a nosql database.

Following the normalization procedures in any good, college-level textbook, normalize every relation to 5NF. Then translate the results to your target platform. (You'll often have to translate declarative code to procedural code.)